# How to set the datatype of missing elements of an Object?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I am trying to duplicate a basic use of Python's [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict), specifically the fact that if a key does not exist, an Array is assumed as the value.

This is to be able to do

```
mydict.hello.push(1)
```

even when `hello` does not exist.

I tried to use [Proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) for that but I think I do not understand how it actually works:

```js
let defaultDict = new Proxy({}, {
  set: (target, name) => {
    if (target.name === undefined) {
      target.name = []
    }
  }
})

let a = defaultDict
a.hello.push(1)
a.hello.push(2)
a.world.push(1)
console.log(a)
```

The error `Cannot read property 'push' of undefined` is exactly what I am trying to avoid.

Should `defaultDict` be somehow instantiated?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining

Comment: `a.hello.push` doesn't set anything?

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of issues:

1. You declared a *setter* (`set`), but what you want is a *getter*. When you do `a.hello`, you are *getting* the value, to then push to it
2. In JS, when you want to use a variable as a property name, you need to use the bracket notation: `target[name]`, because `target.name` refers litterally to a prop named "name"
3. Since it's a getter, you also need to return the value

Here is a working example:

```js
const a = new Proxy({}, {
  get: (target, name) => {
    if (target[name] === undefined) {
      target[name] = [];
    }
    return target[name];
  }
});

a.hello.push(1);
a.hello.push(2);
a.world.push(1);
console.log(a);
```

Here, you'll see that the Object also has a property `toJSON`. That is because StackSnippet looked for a `toJSON` prop on it, the value was not there, so your proxy created it. It's one of the side effects to look after.